# Much faster connection and yet worse video conferencing - how can that be?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, modem

I replaced my old modem and router with a used Netgear C6300BD modem which has a built-in router

I did this because Spectrum claimed they had raised my speed from 100 mbps to 400 but my old modem was not capable of such a speed.

My speed is much better now. It used to be around 15 mbps. Now when I connect to the 5ghz ssid sometimes it goes as high as 200mbps according to  speedtest.net.

And yet my video conferences on Zoom is MUCH WORSE than before. It hangs constantly. And not just on one device; I tried on another laptop too. On my old setup it hung very rarely. Also noticed that YouTube on Samsung smart tv also takes it awhile to show the thumbnails.

Does anyone know why this is? Something about "latency"?  **But the internet provider is the same company. So something wrong with the new modem? How can I troubleshoot this?**

I did a test at this place: https://packetlosstest.com/
And it says my avg. latency is 194 ms and avg jitter is 198 ms.
screenshot here: https://static.md/da00cd158964d46a5df880af64ecfe65.png

But the speedtest software I installed on my laptop says my jitter is only 6.87 and my ping is 12 ms.

So I don't which is right and how to know for sure.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can't say I like the sound of a used cable modem. they generally only live 3 years anyway. I usually take the ISP modem (but ask for non-refurb), and put my own router behind it. Whats mine is mine and whats theirs is theirs. I know thats not all that helpful, but back before I started buying higher grade routers, I used to see problems like this shortly before they gave up the ghost. But that's just one possibility. You may be having an issue with your billing codes (thats happened to me a few times) and it results in slow connections, or bad traffic prioritization.

Comment: Your average latency is pretty irrelevant, however that graph is showing massive latency spikes - and yes, particularly for video conferencing this is bad - and if you solve it you will likely solve your problem.

Comment: Your C6300BD appears to be an 8x4 modem from what I can find online. That means it supports 8 downstream channels, which, generously, provide 40Mbps each, for a total of 320Mbps. More conservatively, it's more like just 200Mbps. If you have 400Mbps downstream sevice, you should upgrade to a modem with at least 16 downstream channels. Be sure to avoid everything on the badmodems.com list of known-bad modems.

Comment: Spiff, vow, this is very interesting. So Netgear's claim about 1900 (600+1300) Mbps (https://www.netgear.com/service-providers/products/cable/gateways/C6300BD-Cox.aspx) that's more marketing fabrication? I will definitely check out badmodems.com. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for response.  what do you mean by "issue with your billing codes"?

Comment: Companies like Spectrum offer a huge range of individual services and run a lot of hardware of different types with different capabilities. For instance when they were Time Warner, they sold wifi for an up-charge, but supplied non-wifi customers hardware that would run wifi, but only if unlocked. The subscribers service codes define the entitlements they are supposed to receive, and its integrated with their device and network control operations, so changing a billing code in the central db would turn on wifi automatically.

Comment: (2/2) Billing codes will define a lot of stuff the subscriber doesn't know is there, and it impacts the way their hardware functions. not all devices work with all codes, and not all possible code settings can be combined.  so there's a lot a new tech can get wrong. usually a person detects issues with service in conjunction with a new modem, but your modem won't react to their codes or netops systems at all, so it may not be able to work with their side of the configuration for your subscription. QOS in particular may not work correctly since you may be unable to fully pair with their config.

Answer (score 1):

When you are on Wi-Fi, it could be anything: your neighbour has an AP on the same channel, you have a radar nearby or noisy microwave. Or your ISP is overloaded with requests from other users.

Your jitter is relatively high, bigger than ping, which means that your ping even doubles sometimes. It could be that your connection is unstable. Try the same test on wired connection with Ethernet cable and check if you get the same results.

Comment: Hi Konradmb, Thanks for response. I will test on Ethernet and report back. Again, the internet provider is the same company, the lines to coming to house the same. But what do you mean by " neighbor has an AP on the same channel" ? Forgive my ignorance.

Comment: Konradmb is referring to electromagnetic interference from a neighbors wifi. In general sources of interference prevent radio devices like your laptop and wifi router from receiving understandable messages from each other, because the message was distorted in transit. this may cause messages to be resent, increasing the work and latency involved in the task at hand. while interference may or may not be a problem for you, wifi does have higher latency in general than wired networking so it is worth trying, though I'd lean more toward cheap hardware being the cause of problem.